# Maximum sounds effect in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I tried to repetitive press sound effect, each MP3 is 8 secs long and as fast as I press the button, it suddenly hang for a few seconds before I could continue execute the sound effect again.

I use the code in http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=createeffects_2.html
After **Example: Passing parameters to effects** and I modify one of the code `rollovereffect` to `mousedowneffct` in MainSoundParam.mxml

Is it possible to have the sound effect load and play 50 or 100 instances at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

No more than 8 (or 16, don't remember) sounds can be played concurrently. It is Flash Player restriction.